# using ThinRDC (thinomenon) on Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to run a remoteApp hosted on a windows 7 enterprise, from an Ubuntu client 14.01. I was looking to use FreeRDP or Winconn, but the issue with those is that Winconn is based on FreeRDP and because of that the clipboard does not sync.

Browsing around, I found [thinomenon](http://www.thinomenon.com/products/RemoteDesktopClient/linux.aspx#details) that looks like actually has support for the clipboard, but it is not a deb, and in the [support forum](http://www.thinomenon.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=434) they explain how to use it to connect to a remoteApp, the problem is that they use an older version, they say:

```
mkdir thinrdc && tar -xzf thinrdc_linux_ubuntu-0.2.1.tgz -C thinrdc
cd thinrdc
./accessclient --file "file.rdp"
```

So the new 0.3.1 version the "accessclient" just doesn't exist, there is one called "thinrdc" which i tried to run without any luck..

```
./thinrdc --file "file.rdp"
```

Does anyone know how to make it work?

The support forum is useless because there are questions about this same issue without answer, so I decided to ask here.

I believe the clipboard issue is something many are looking forward to be able to use, and this may be the solution!! shame is that the thinomenon project looks like is abandoned..

thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you try xfreerdp with the `+clipboard` command line option, usually works for me.

Comment: @Shutupsquare it works when you are connecting on full RDP, but when I try with remoteApp only: `--app` clipboard does not redirect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also like to know how to establish a RemoteApp-Connection. I figured that running `./thinrdc` will start up the gui, but I dont know how to go on from there.

[image: Thinomenon Remote Desktop Connection]

Comment: Acutally I tried `./thinrdc --file "file.rdp"` again and it works. Tough I would love to see more options for the commandline.